# How to repeat a function with the same parameters at a given time interval (currently trying to use setTimout)

Tags: javascript, html, timing

I have a very basic function that gets the digital time and was wondering if it would be possible to make the "elementToChange" a parameter. When I try to do it, it gets stuck on the setTimout function because it doesn't take the same parameters.

Is there any way to change the code so that I could simply give the  element to change as a parameter and still repeat the function at a given time interval?

```
function setDigitalTime(){
  let today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  if(m < 10){m = "0" + m;}
  if(s < 10){s = "0" + s;}
  document.getElementById("elementToChange").innerHTML = h+" : "+m+" : "+s;
  setTimeout(setDigitalTime,500);
}
```

Comment: use setInterval(func, 500);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout`'s additional arguments after the first and second are the parameters to call the callback function with. eg `setTimeout((arg) => console.log(arg), 500, 'foo')` will print `foo` after 500 ms. So, one option would be to use the parameter passed to `setDigitalTime` as `setTimeout`'s third parameter:

```
function setDigitalTime(id){
  let today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  if(m < 10){m = "0" + m;}
  if(s < 10){s = "0" + s;}
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = h+" : "+m+" : "+s;
  setTimeout(setDigitalTime, 500, id);
}
```

You can follow the same pattern for additional arguments - the fourth argument passed to `setTimeout` represents the *second* argument to call the callback function with, and so on.

Another option would be to have an anonymous inline function that calls `setDigitalTime(id)`:

```
function setDigitalTime(id){
  let today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  if(m < 10){m = "0" + m;}
  if(s < 10){s = "0" + s;}
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = h+" : "+m+" : "+s;
  setTimeout(() => setDigitalTime(id), 500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you think setInterval would be better here or does it not matter?

Comment: `setInterval` can work, but habitually using a recursive `setTimout` is just fine and even [preferred](https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9) by some. It's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  function setDigitalTime(setElement){
    let today = new Date();
    let h = today.getHours();
    let m = today.getMinutes();
    let s = today.getSeconds();
    if(m < 10){m = "0" + m;}
    if(s < 10){s = "0" + s;}
    document.getElementById(setElement).innerHTML = h+" : "+m+" : "+s;

  } 

  // Change to call onload.
  (function(){
    setInterval(() => { setDigitalTime('elementToChange') },500);
  })();
```

```html
<div id="elementToChange"></div>
```

Comment: I already have this I wanted to know how to make the id of the element to change a parameter

Comment: Will edit for that. Do you want to set seperate timers on a page as well?

Comment: no the timer is fine if the third parameter of setTimer is the parameters of the function to call then I can do it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either approach. But I would lean toward a method that was called 'startDigitalTimer' if the method is to be endlessly recursive by calling 'setTimeout'. It really is a matter of taste.